# Pywinauto: click Chrome's tab

Tags: python, google-chrome, pywinauto

Using this code to access Chrome and its window using **Python** and **pywinauto**:

```
from pywinauto import application

app = application.Application()
app.connect(title_re=".*Chrome.*")
dlg = app.top_window_()
```

Getting a list of controls (suppose, the tab is a control as well):

```
dlg.PrintControlIdentifiers()
```

It returns something like:

```
Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND - 'Chrome Legacy Window'   (L0, T90, R1920, B1160)
    'Chrome Legacy Window' 'Chrome Legacy Window0' 'Chrome Legacy Window1' 'Chrome Legacy WindowChrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND' 'Chrome Legacy WindowChrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND0' 'Chrome Legacy WindowChrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1' 'Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND' 'Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND0' 'Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1' ()
```

The goal is to click on one of the tabs in the Chrome browser.

Any ideas how to access Chrome's tabs?

**EDIT:** I found that it can be accessed using:

```
dlg.Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND.Exists()
```

Now, the goal is to click it, since `.Click()` seems not to work.

Comment: Chrome doesn't support native widgets having its own hwnd. But it can be automated using pywinauto/UIA branch on GitHub. Additionally Chrome must run with `--force-renderer-accessibility` cmd param. We have plans to write an example for Chrome after pywinauto 0.6.0 release planned in October.

Comment: I see, thank you for explanation.

Comment: Some initial example for `explorer.exe` can found here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/0.6.0-README-prototype Early feedback is welcome. :)

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Just curious, is it possible to set mouse coords and click using pywinauto? (this can help me solve Google automation for now). Something similar to: `win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))`?

Comment: With pywinauto/UIA you can call `from pywinauto import mouse; mouse.click(coords=(x,y))`. Unfortunately pywinauto 0.5.4 has no standalone `mouse` submodule yet.

Comment: You can try to install pywinauto/UIA with `pip install git+https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto.git@UIA` (worked for me).